# React + Redux + JS SDK events

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working with a JS SDK which has an event that fires when someone comments, the event will return some data which I want to store in redux, what is the best way to update my redux state whenever the SDK fires that event.

What is the best way to do this with react + redux.
I only want to handle this logic once. Would I make a container for ?

Comment: What do you want to do basically by updating state? The question is not clear

Comment: Whenever the SDK event is fired the data that is returned I want to put into redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When event returns the data, You have to call `action creator` with the data as an argument. So, your action creator function looks like this:

```
export const addData = (data) => {
    return {
       type: SAVE_DATA
       payload: data
    };
};
```

Then in reducer just update the state. Your reducer function should something like this:

```
export const reducerFunction = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SAVE_DATA':
            return action.payload.data;
    }
}
```

Add action creator in dispatchToProps, and call when your event returns the data as: `this.props.addData(data)`